# Python - implement __iter__ or return a list's __iter__

Tags: python, iterator

I'm implementing what is essentially a container object (although it does have a little of it's own logic). I want to be able to iterate over items in a field in this class (which is just a plain list). Should I re-implement `__iter__` and `next` for my class or is it acceptable to return the iterator of the list, like so:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self):
       self.list = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.list.__iter__()
```

I'm a little unsure if this will lead to any undesirable behavior.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is fine to use the iterator of the built-in `list` type.  I'd suggest not to call `__iter__()` explicitly, though, but rather use the built-in function `iter()`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.list)
```

Another option might be to derive `X` from `list`.  (In Python 2.x, you should at least derive from `object`.)